# How to convert string Date to Timestamp in Java for the format dd-MMM-yyyy?

Tags: java, sql

I want to convert string Date to Timestamp in java. The following are the codes that I have written. The date value passed is in the format *19-SEP-2013*.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = dateFormat.parse(tcmo.getCtsDate());
ps.setTimestamp(ctr++, new Timestamp(date.getTime());
```

The variable *ctr* is declared already. *ps* is the `PreparedStatement` object. Later codes include `ps.executeUpdate()`.

`tcmo.getCtsDate()` returns the value 19-Sep-2013.

Database can accept only Timestamp in the format **2013-09-19 00:00:00.0**

The exception thrown is `Unparseable Date "19-SEP-2013"`. can anyone help me to clear this?

Comment: What type of `Object` does `tcmo.getCtsDate()` return?

Answer (score 2):

Your format `String` (`yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss`) and your input (`19-SEP-2013`) don't match.

A format of `dd-MMM-yyyy` would be required to parse the `String` to a `Date` object

For example...

```
try {
    String text = "19-SEP-2013";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    Date date = sdf.parse(text);
    System.out.println(text + " to " + date);
} catch (ParseException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Outputs...

```
19-SEP-2013 to Thu Sep 19 00:00:00 EST 2013
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm not sure I understand the question.  The formatter matters greatly and it needs to be able to know in what form the input is coming in order to know best to treat each part of the `String`...

Comment: I meant since the end goal is to insert into a database. You can just create a timestamp object from the time in milliseconds.

Comment: Yep, the OP does this...`new Timestamp(date.getTime())`, the problem seems to be getting the `String` value into a `Date` object...or I'm missing the point :P

Comment: No you got it, I didn't.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks for wanting to help out though :) Always appreciate a helping hand none-the-less ;)

Comment: 19-SEP-2013 to Thu Sep 19 00:00:00 EST 2013, Does this will sit properly into the database?

Comment: Well, since all you really want to do is `new Timestamp(date.getTime())`, it should be fine...The output was example to demonstrate that the `String` was parsed correctly...

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the first line with

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

This should resolve the parsing error.

Further information about SimpleDateFormat, including what are valid letters, [can be found in the Oracle JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is a "gotcha" that traps many programmers new to java. The format character `m` is for *minutes* and `M` is for *months*..

Your format string of `"yyyy-mm-dd"` is effectively `years-minutes-days`.

Change the format string to `"yyyy-MM-dd..."` and it will fix the problem.